# Problem displaying one post from each category

Tags: categories

i had been banging my head for almost a day but could not resolve it.
i need to show one post from 4 xx categories here is my code

```
                <?php
                $cat_args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'name',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'include' => '44,45,46,51'
                );

                $fcategories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

                foreach($fcategories as $fcategory) {
                    echo '<dl>';
                    echo '<dt> <a href="' . get_category_link( $fcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $fcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $fcategory->name.'</a></dt>';

                     $post_args = array(
                      'showposts' => 1,
                      'category' => $fcategory->cat_ID
                    );

                    $fposts = get_posts($post_args);

                foreach($fposts as $fpost) : setup_postdata($fpost);    ?>
                        <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
                    <?php

                    echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $fcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $fcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $fcategory->name.'</a></dd>';
                    echo '</dl>';
                endforeach; 
                    }
                ?>
```

Every think seem to work perfectly except....  its showing only one post for all category while it should have shown one post from each category
to be more specific its showing like

cat-1  cat-2    cat-3  cat-4 (this is ok)
post-1 post-1  post-1  post-1 (this is the prob)

while it should have been

cat-1  cat-2    cat-3  cat-4
post-1 post-2  post-3  post-4

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked this code localy, here is the working snippet:

```
        <?php
        $cat_args = array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                );

        $fcategories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

        foreach($fcategories as $fcategory) {
            echo '<dl>';
            echo '<dt> <a href="' . get_category_link( $fcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $fcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $fcategory->name.'</a></dt>';

            $post_args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'cat' => $fcategory->cat_ID
                    );

            $fposts = query_posts($post_args);

            while(have_posts()) : the_post();    ?>
                <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
                <?php

                echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $fcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $fcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $fcategory->name.'</a></dd>';
            echo '</dl>';
            endwhile; 
        }
        wp_query_reset();
?>
```

---

**Original answer**:
I think the problem might be here:

```
$post_args = array(
  'showposts' => 1,
  'category' => $fcategory->cat_ID
);
```

you're using `category` argument, it should be `cat` so try this code:

```
$post_args = array(
  'showposts' => 1,
  'cat' => $fcategory->cat_ID
);
```

Comment: no, 'category' is correct for get_post, as per codex

Comment: but have you tried using `cat` ? It might be a misstake in a `get_posts()` codex page because almost every other wordpress function (which is based on [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)) uses `cat` argument. You can also try using `query_posts()` instead of `get_posts()`

Comment: i have tried 'cat' but its not working, query_posts will replace the main query on my front page, this is the second query for featured section

Comment: yes, that's true, that's why while using query_posts, you can add `wp_reset_query()` after your custom loop to avoid such problem. That's how i was allways doing custom loops, `query_posts()` + `wp_query_reset()` and it allways works :)

Comment: it did not work for me :( even after reset_qery

Comment: check out my answer, i've tested your code on my wordpress installation and fixed it. The working snippet is in original answer.

Comment: i will give a + for your effort, i will check this and get back to you